# Setting components on two JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a little bit of a problem with understanding Java layouts. I am using `GridBagLayout`to position components on two separate `JPanel` and then adding panels to `JFrame`like this:

```
    upperContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    lowerContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    getContentPane().add(upperContainer, BorderLayout.NORTH);       
    getContentPane().add(lowerContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now, the program is doing exactly what I expect, but not what I want. It puts the `ùpperContainer`(with all its components) above the `lowerContainer`, but there is a a huge gap between components of these two panels. See screenshot below. I marked the gap with an arrow. I want my components on the `lowerContainer`to be positioned higher so it looks nicer. 
Here is the piece of code (only for `lowerContainer`):
EDIT: I used `.createEtchedBorder`function on both panels so the borders of the panels are better seen.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;
    import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    public class ConvertAllSystem extends JFrame{

    private JLabel labelDistance, labelWeight; 
    private JTextArea distanceOutput, weightOutput;
    private JTextField distanceInput, weightInput;
    private JButton convert, convert1; 
    private JComboBox fromListDistance, toListDistance, fromListWeight, toListWeight; 

    private String[] convertFromDistance = {"From (distance)...", "Mile", "Knot", "Kilometer", "Centimeter", "Meter", "Inch", "Yard"}; 
    private String[] convertToDistance = {"To (distance)...", "Mile", "Knot", "Kilometer", "Centimeter", "Meter", "Inch", "Yard"}; 
    private String[] convertFromWeight = {"From (weight)...", "Pound", "Kilogram", "Celcius", "Fahrenheit", "Gallon", "Liter"}; 
    private String[] convertToWeight = {"To (weight)...", "Pound", "Kilogram", "Celcius", "Fahrenheit", "Gallon", "Liter"}; 

    private Font font;
    JSeparator lineBetween;

    //Initialize all GUI components 
    private void createAllComponents() {

    JPanel upperContainer = new JPanel();
    JPanel lowerContainer = new JPanel();
    upperContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    lowerContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    getContentPane().add(upperContainer, BorderLayout.NORTH);       
    getContentPane().add(lowerContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Border outputCenter;    

     GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20); 
    labelDistance = new JLabel("Convert distance unit");
    labelDistance.setFont(font);
    labelWeight = new JLabel("Convert weight unit");
    labelWeight.setFont(font);      

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,10,0);
    upperContainer.add(labelDistance, c);

    fromListDistance = new JComboBox<String>(convertFromDistance);
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.ipady = 5;
    c.ipadx = 30;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,20,0,5);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    upperContainer.add(fromListDistance, c);

    toListDistance = new JComboBox<String>(convertToDistance);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    upperContainer.add(toListDistance, c);

    distanceInput = new JTextField("Enter value here...");
    distanceInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));;
    distanceInput.setEditable(true);
    distanceInput.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            distanceInput.setText("");}});
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.ipady = 1;
    c.ipadx = 5;
    c.weightx = 5.0;
    upperContainer.add(distanceInput, c);

    convert = new JButton("Convert");
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.ipady = 20;
    c.ipadx = 50;
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    upperContainer.add(convert, c);

    distanceOutput = new JTextArea(5,30);
    distanceOutput.setEditable(false);
    distanceOutput.setText("                                            Output");
    distanceOutput.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    outputCenter = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED);
    distanceOutput.setBorder(outputCenter);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.ipady = 1;
    c.ipadx = 5;
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    c.insets = new Insets(30,0,0,0);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    upperContainer.add(distanceOutput, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx =0.5;
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    lowerContainer.add(labelWeight, c);

    fromListWeight = new JComboBox<String>(convertFromWeight);
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 1.5;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.ipady = 5;
    c.ipadx = 30;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,20,0,5);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    lowerContainer.add(fromListWeight, c);

    toListWeight = new JComboBox<String>(convertToWeight);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    lowerContainer.add(toListWeight, c);

    weightInput = new JTextField("Enter value here...");
    weightInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));;
    weightInput.setEditable(true);
    weightInput.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            weightInput.setText("");}});
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.ipady = 2;
    c.ipadx = 10;
    c.weightx = 5.0;
    lowerContainer.add(weightInput, c);

    convert1 = new JButton("Convert");
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.ipady = 20;
    c.ipadx = 50;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    lowerContainer.add(convert1, c);

    weightOutput = new JTextArea(5,30);
    weightOutput.setEditable(false);
    weightOutput.setText("                                            Output");
    weightOutput.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    weightOutput.setBorder(outputCenter);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.ipady = 1;
    c.ipadx = 5;
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    c.insets = new Insets(30,30,0,0);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    lowerContainer.add(weightOutput, c);

}

//Constractor
public ConvertAllSystem() {
    createAllComponents();
    setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    setTitle("Converting App"); 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700, 700);
    setResizable(true); 
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        new ConvertAllSystem(); 
    });

}
```

}

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you setting the size or the preferred size of the entire application? Are you calling `pack()`? If you're artificially setting the size, the center positioned component will expand to fill the size, causing the problems you're seeing. Please post a *valid* [mcve] so we can test your actual code for ourselves.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter here is the entire code:

Comment: Sorry, it took some times to put the whole code. @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter

Comment: As a general recommendation, I would suggest using using a `GridLayout` on the content pane itself, `getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2 0));` then simply add your other components, this should layout them out one on top of the other, BUT will fill the available space.  The use `pack` over `setSize`

Comment: @MadProgrammer: yep, or `GridLayout(0, 1)` as per my answer which allows for 1 column and variable number of rows.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: and thank you for the correction regarding `setBounds` on the other Swing question. I have deleted my dubious answer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer & @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter - you guys rock! Thank you. This answered my trouble :). One additional question though....`pack()` is making the main frame smaller (fitting the components of course). I want my frame a bit bigger so when it is opened not only components are shown but a bit of space also. Any ways to do that? Thanks!!!

Comment: @sumu00 Consider using one or more `EmptyBorder`s to add additional padding around the content pane or individual components

Comment: @MadProgrammer, oh why haven't I thought about that :). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected there's your problem:

```
    setSize(700, 700);
```

By artificially sizing the GUI, you're adding extra space that the BorderLayout will fill with blank space.

Change this to:

```
    // setSize(700, 700);
    pack();
```

Let the layouts and components size themselves

Note also that if you're creating two similar JPanels, one on top of the other, don't put them into a BorderLayout-using container, but rather a `GridLayout(0, 1)` using container:

```
    JPanel upperContainer = new JPanel();
    JPanel lowerContainer = new JPanel();
    upperContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    lowerContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    // getContentPane().add(upperContainer, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    // getContentPane().add(lowerContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    getContentPane().add(upperContainer);
    getContentPane().add(lowerContainer);
```

Comment: This really is only a partial solution. Yes the pack() will display the components at their preferred size. However, if the user ever resizes the frame, then you will get space between the components again as a GridLayout will give equal space to each component. The original problem with the spacing is because the GridBagLayout will center all components in the space available. So changing layouts really hasn't changed the problem. A better solution might be to nest panels. Create a vertical box layout for the two components. Add this panel to the NORTH. The panels will now never grow.

Comment: Of course if you use `setResizable( false )`, then the above doesn't apply.